# SFTP logging configuration fails with an error (OpenSSH 5.1)

Tags: ssh, logging, openssl, sftp

Adding following line to sshd_config

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f LOCAL5 -l INFO
```

When i start sshd service it fails with error

```
"garbage at the end of line : -f"
```

My openssh version is 5.1 on RHEL 5

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The man page for sshd_config isn't really clear about this, but does it work if you put quotes around the command and arguments?  `Subsystem sftp "/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -f LOCAL5 -l INFO"`

Comment: sshd does accept arguments on the subsystem line. See http://superuser.com/a/847303/54530. Your example line works fine for me, using OpenSSH 6.6.

Comment: I tried using quotes as suggested by @Andrew Schulman but the problem persists, however it worked under RHEL 5.9 with same SSH version and configuration.